# MaxProductOfThree how to increase the performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o, python-itertools

MaxProductOfThree lesson : https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/6-sorting/max_product_of_three/

For solving this Codility lesson I've coded this function like below;

```
import itertools

def solution(A):
    combs=[]

    for pivot_element in A:
        to_comb=A[A.index(pivot_element):]

        for comb in itertools.combinations(to_comb, 3):
           mul_comb= comb[0] * comb[1] * comb[2]
           combs.append(mul_comb) 

    return max(combs)
```

My results were,

```
result_of_algorithm={
                    "correctness":100,
                    "performance":0,
                    "overall":44,
                    "time complexity": "O(N^3)"
                    }
```

How can I increase its performance to O(n) time complexity? Can you please explain?

Comment: Sort and then multiply the last three items - ```O(NlogN)```

Comment: @Ram And then do some other stuff as well so you always get the correct answer.

Comment: @Ram exactly O(N * logN) is the optimal

Comment: @BerkeŞentürk I what way is O(N * logN) optimal when O(N) is possible?

Answer (score 4):

O(n) version of schwobaseggl's solution, also got 100%:

```
from heapq import nsmallest, nlargest

def solution(A):
    a, b = nsmallest(2, A)
    z, y, x = nlargest(3, A)
    return max(a*b*z, x*y*z)
```

Benchmarks with the largest allowed case (100,000 values from -1000 to 1000):

```
204 ms  206 ms  208 ms  210 ms  212 ms  sort
 76 ms   77 ms   78 ms   79 ms   81 ms  heapq
134 ms  135 ms  135 ms  135 ms  136 ms  oneloop
144 ms  146 ms  147 ms  149 ms  151 ms  twoloops
  3 ms    3 ms    3 ms    3 ms    4 ms  baseline
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VXBbqMwEL3zFXOpapATBbisos1KfEcUIRNMYy02rO2oSX4@HdtA2ShU6r0cMJ438@aNGY37qz11Kv/V6/u90Z0EKyQXFoTsO21B854zG3lEM1XjMiDHUyeO3AToxFn/b0SUkaxtubEUVMv0G35FA2SuJopq3oDBHSnibQT4FGu/jf2mT2EHxX5zgASXNCyr9BDAzIOrfDBn/8Oa27NWINmF9ClF7zhk8/KmdIxChTSTTJJRKELyG4UrhYtDB@Ukn8AZO0uqBH0vyTW5DTk6xduu66csUihXCVa8xggjbhylZiOULUHs4qJWC1j2BZYvYU2noRAgFBRBmntE42y/d17np3kmzwGPdv9vxGTl7Zwme0ozcw/Of3a@ygfnoN@V@GjPgj19tC9oCfTZt@gXafKnNIP7rB/2/mySUHPi1dGgMQk5/JIfhl6x753rFfPTLM@b5QsRP90DFTOYR/Gpe3pmcKw2Z3U0rlNwltIw8ug4lejUcnQKxwg85tKdMk72N07ycRwjyTDdSUBW6WazoYDvNKbwd4cfJVri6We53I7Ia/is2t0loyRek3CZkJbJqmZb70yK/faAnOosK66ROI6n6F4LZUlCXl/yGqSBV3gBYvEwUp7HPq11OX0SpHB067JUTPKyHO4SzxDf7x8)):

```
from timeit import repeat
from random import choices
from heapq import nsmallest, nlargest
import sys

def sort(A):
    A.sort()
    p1 = A[0] * A[1] * A[-1]
    p2 = A[-3] * A[-2] * A[-1]
    return max(p1, p2)

def heapq(A):
    a, b = nsmallest(2, A)
    z, y, x = nlargest(3, A)
    return max(a*b*z, x*y*z)

def oneloop(A):
    min1 = sys.maxsize * 2
    min2 = sys.maxsize * 2
    max1 = -sys.maxsize * 2
    max2 = -sys.maxsize * 2
    max3 = -sys.maxsize * 2
    for Ai in A:
        if Ai <= min1:
            min2 = min1
            min1 = Ai
        elif Ai <= min2:
            min2 = Ai
        if Ai >= max1:
            max3 = max2
            max2 = max1
            max1 = Ai
        elif Ai >= max2:
            max3 = max2
            max2 = Ai
        elif Ai >= max3:
            max3 = Ai
    return max([min1 * min2 * max1, max1 * max2 * max3])

def twoloops(A):
    min1 = sys.maxsize * 2
    min2 = sys.maxsize * 2
    max1 = -sys.maxsize * 2
    max2 = -sys.maxsize * 2
    max3 = -sys.maxsize * 2
    for Ai in A:
        if Ai <= min1:
            min2 = min1
            min1 = Ai
        elif Ai <= min2:
            min2 = Ai
    for Ai in A:
        if Ai >= max1:
            max3 = max2
            max2 = max1
            max1 = Ai
        elif Ai >= max2:
            max3 = max2
            max2 = Ai
        elif Ai >= max3:
            max3 = Ai
    return max([min1 * min2 * max1, max1 * max2 * max3])

def baseline(A):
    pass

funcs = sort, heapq, oneloop, twoloops, baseline

for _ in range(3):
    A = choices(range(-1000, 1001), k=100_000)
    for func in funcs:
        times = sorted(repeat(lambda: func(A[:]), number=10))
        print(*('%3d ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in times), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: This is a really short and clean solution and in  `O(n)` although calling `nsmallest` and `nlargest` is iterating `A` twice.

Comment: @Leonard It's a list, it doesn't mind being iterated twice :-)

Comment: Of course not but it's possible with one iteration. Weird thing is that Codility detects `O(n log(n))` for both mine and your solution which are both in `O(n)`.

Comment: I tried quite the same as this, but it was detected as log-linear. According to the docs this should be linear, I agree.

Comment: @Leonard Yeah, but I'm sure most of the work is done by *handling* the values, not by iterating them. Your single iteration is slower than each of two separate iterations would be. It's probably not much faster than the two together would be.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Hard to distinguish automatically, I guess. It certainly is linear. But is that in the docs? I only know it from the source code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `heapq` module is written in pure Python, and for most use cases, the algorithmic advantages of this approach are eaten up by the brute C-speed of just sorting. But this is the most elegant way, no doubt ;-)

Comment: @schwobaseggl There are also [705 lines of C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_heapqmodule.c).

Comment: Ah, that's true. I just found https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/heapq.py

Comment: @schwobaseggl Always look for the imports :-). I this case [these](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/793f55bde9b0299100c12ddb0e6949c6eb4d85e5/Lib/heapq.py#L578-L595).

Comment: How it is O(N * logN) I didn't figure it out?

Comment: @BerkeŞentürk What do you mean?

Comment: I'm very amateur in Big O notation so I didn't get why it is hasn't O(N^3) like complexity. Doesn't nsmallest or nlargest contain O(n) complexity?

Comment: @BerkeŞentürk nsmallest and nlargest are O(|A|) here. I have no idea why you're thinking of O(N^3).

Answer (score 2):

Naively, you can do this in log-linear time:

```
def solution(A):
    A.sort()
    p1 = A[0] * A[1] * A[-1]
    p2 = A[-3] * A[-2] * A[-1]
    return max(p1, p2)
```

The sorting allows you to just try the numbers on both extremes of the sort order. The two options account for the possibility of including negative numbers. It achieves 100% on both correctness and performance.

Comment: You don't "just try the numbers with the largest absolute values", though. Fortunately, you also try the numbers with the *smallest* absolute values when that's necessary, for example for `[-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]`.

Comment: True, one should say the ones on both extremes of the sort order.

Comment: This is possible in linear time, you don't need to sort the array - it doesn't achieve 100% in performance.

Comment: @Leonard Even mine, which also sorted and then did *more* work, achieved 100%.

Comment: I misunderstood you. I thought you meant that this is the optimal solution in terms of time complexity which it isn't.

Comment: Still not 100% sure it's right, but wrote a heapq version with imho cute variable names. Didn't know the term "log-linear", but [found it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Quasilinear_time). Might want to use the k=1 name "linearithmic".

Comment: @schwobaseggl If `k` is the number of smallest/largest elements to detect and `n` the number of items in the list, they have complexity `O(n log(k))`. Here, `k` is a constant so it's `O(n)`. My solution is definitely `O(n)` (it's just one iteration and a constant number of comparisons) and it still detects `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: @Leonard True. Yours is definitely linear, just doesn't look so elegant :-)

Comment: Added a benchmark to my answer. Also @Leonard

Comment: And now I **fixed** my answer's benchmark and the results are very different :-) Also @Leonard

Answer (score 1):

From this source I've reached a very simple solution: https://youtu.be/qr3i9cXAjbc

The Algorithm is the same algorithm in the answer of @schwobaseggl and simply like below. Works %100 in both performance and correctness.

```
def solution(A):
    A.sort()
    N=len(A)

    P1 = A[N-1] * A[0] * A[1]
    P2 = A[N-1] * A[N-2] * A[N-3]

    return max(P1,P2)
```

Comment: Can you try it now?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is described here: https://afteracademy.com/blog/maximum-product-of-three-numbers

There are only two possible options:

1. You need the three biggest numbers (this is obviously the case if all numbers are positive)
2. You need the biggest number and the two smallest numbers. This can only happen if the two smallest numbers are negative and if their product is larger than the product of the second and third largest numbers. Clearly, the product of the two smallest numbers then is positive and you then need to multiply it with the largest number.

You need to check both cases and return whatever is larger. I adapted the code from the link to Python. It has time complexity `O(n)` as we iterate through the list only one:

```
# solution.py
import sys


def solution(A):
    min1 = sys.maxsize * 2
    min2 = sys.maxsize * 2
    max1 = -sys.maxsize * 2
    max2 = -sys.maxsize * 2
    max3 = -sys.maxsize * 2

    for Ai in A:
        if Ai <= min1:
            min2 = min1
            min1 = Ai
        elif Ai <= min2:
            min2 = Ai
        if Ai >= max1:
            max3 = max2
            max2 = max1
            max1 = Ai
        elif Ai >= max2:
            max3 = max2
            max2 = Ai
        elif Ai >= max3:
            max3 = Ai
    return max([min1 * min2 * max1, max1 * max2 * max3])
```

For example, `print(solution([-11, -10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))` gives you `990` (`-11 * -10 * 9`)

Comment: Btw if you want infinity, without numpy, you can also use `float('inf')` or `math.inf`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
def maxproduct(a):
    i = 0
    max_three = [float('-inf')]
    idx = []
    while i < len(a) - 1:
        temp = max(a[i:i+2])
        if temp > max_three[-1]:
            max_three.append(temp)
        i +=1
        
    return [a.index(e) for e in (max_three[-3:])]
    
maxproduct(a)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).